# why a = "b"; hello:a returns "b"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was telling to a colleage in work that `[1].map(e => {attr:e});` will not do what he thinks. He was thinking that the return will be `[{attr: 1}]`.

I though that node will crash with this code, but for my surprise, when I open the node program in the terminal, if I write that line is not crashing, is returning `[undefined]` in node 8. And if I write `a = "b"; hello:a` it returns `"b"`.

What is happening there?

Comment: It's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: `forEach` always returns `undefined`, to begin with.

Comment: `Array.foreach` return is `undefined`, you perhaps means about `Array.map`. Edit: @Yury Tarabanko exact same time :p

Comment: Sorry, I mean .map. An error of the question.